# If statement not excepting line of text?

Tags: c++

This code should ask for in put with "What is If (selection)?"
and this part it does. but once you input the answer as "Provides the ability to either do a block of code or skip that block of code." the out come should be "Correct!" but instead it either asks to press key to end or re asks the question. does anyone have and advice as to how i could fix this?

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
int random_interger;
int lowest = 2, highest = 18;
int range = (highest - lowest) + 1;
for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
    random_interger = lowest + int(range*rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));


if (random_interger == IF) {
        cout << " What is If (selection)?" << endl;
        cin >> IFs;



if (IFs == "Provides the ability to either do a block of code or 
skip that block of code.") {
            cout << "Correct!" << endl;

        }
```

Comment: If you you are in the situation that you don't have a good IDE with an integrated debugger like Visual Studio (that you can step through your code looking at the variables) you can at least use std::cout to print the value of `random_interger` before the if () to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

```
string IFs;
cin >> IFs;
```

Even if the user types exactly the long line you expect (he won't), this wouldn't work. cin >> into a string will read just one word. You would get only "Provides".

Look up the getline API. But even then, I doubt anyone would type those lines exactly.

Comment: You are correct. I wasn't thinking of that issue. Just the difficulty to type exactly the same string.

Comment: i will make sure to look that up thank you :D i see where you're coming from with the long answer part but the reason the line is that long though is because that's how the teacher put it on the paper that tells the definitions. but this is just mostly for me because i wanna practice the language and study at the same time lol. but again thanks for the recommendation :D